# About the path syntax of this JSON

Tags: javascript, json

What would be the syntax path to thumbnails.data?
also, could such an output be simplified, to just `{}'s`, rather than `[]'s` and `{}'s`?

```
{
   "returnValue":true,
   "results":[
      {
         "_id":"++HUS_WBo9OoOpWA",
         "_kind":"com.palm.media.audio.file:1",
         "_rev":3357,
         "album":"Elements of Love: Ballads",
         "albumArtist":"Earth, Wind & Fire",
         "artist":"Earth, Wind & Fire",
         "bookmark":0,
         "createdTime":0,
         "disc":{
            "position":1,
            "total":1
         },
         "duration":0,
         "genre":"Rhythm & Blues",
         "isRingtone":false,
         "modifiedTime":1300682209,
         "path":"/media/internal/Track 03 - Devotion.mp3",
         "searchKey":"Earth, Wind & Fire Elements of Love: Ballads Devotion",
         "size":6976284,
         "sortKey":{
            "trackAndDisc":100003
         },
         "thumbnails":[
            {
               "_id":"d1e",
               "data":"/media/internal/Track 03 - Devotion.mp3:216:5998",
               "type":"embedded"
            }
         ],
         "title":"Devotion",
         "track":{
            "position":3,
            "total":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myData` holds the data structure in question, you would use

```
myData.results[0].thumbnails[0].data
```

As for simplification of your output, yes, it certainly could be simplified, but we'd have to see the code which generates that to tell you how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

1. How do I get to the thumbnails data?

   Assuming your JSON object is stored in the variable `myData`:

   ```
   myData.results[0].thumbnails[0].data
   ```

   Note that this is for the specific example you posted and will *always* return the first thumbnails data for the first result. In actual code, you will probably loop over both the arrays (`results` and `thumbnails`) to extract *all* the thumbnails data for *all* the results objects.
2. Can this JSON object be simplified?

   It most certainly could be - it depends on what the purpose is and how it's being generated. If it's being returned by a webservice that you have no control over, then no, you can't change it, obviously. If you're generating it, then sure, you define the object and it's meaning. For example, you could restrict the number of thumbnails to just 1 always, and so, instead of having an array of thumbnails, you'd have just a thumbnail object.

   However, as I see it right now, it makes a lot sense - your results could include 1 or more items, hence an array; there could more than 1 thumbnail images and so an array is used there as well...

Comment: The json data  does come from a service and not generated by me. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning to have more than one thumbnail per result? If not, you can just have:

```
"thumbnails":{
               "_id":"d1e",
               "data":"/media/internal/Track 03 - Devotion.mp3:216:5998",
               "type":"embedded"
            },
```

and access it as: `results[i].thumbnails.data`